# Can't run grails app in STS after moving it to another pc

Tags: grails

I'm working on a Grails project using STS 3.1, and I need to migrate the project to another PC. I copied the folder to the new environment and ran "refresh dependencies". It worked fine. I ran "grails war" succesfuly. The problem is when I try "run on server" I get the error:

"The archive: *path to grails directory in old pc*/lib/org.codehaus.groovy/groovy-all/jars/groovy-all-1.8.8.jar which is referenced by the classpath, does not exist."

Where can I update this reference ?

Thanks

Comment: Without changing any configuration, now I get a different message:Error occurred during initialization of VM
agent library failed to init: instrument
Error opening zip file or JAR manifest missing : null

Comment: Can you run the app from command line instead of STS ? If yes, check if groovy compiler is set correctly in IDE - Window -> Preferences -> Groovy -> Compiler or Project -> Properties -> Groovy Compiler

Comment: I know with Intellij, I have none of the major issues that wasted my time with STS. Give it a try for 30 days.

Comment: James, was the project migration process (STS->Idea) smooth ?

Comment: Thanks for the tip James, it works perfectly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up migrating to IntelliJ Idea. Let me tell you there's a big difference in features and the price seems right.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try in the .classpath file in the root of the project?